# If, else type thing in JS, how do I do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript:

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
```

And I want to do something like that:
If the `coll[0].style.display = 'block';` and you click on it, it will change to `coll[0].style.display = 'none';`.

(I want it to be possible to change on click display:block to display:none but ONLY when the display is set to block, I hope you know what i mean, please help)

Comment: This is a very simple question; Please search documentation on this before asking this question. Here is an example of what you are try to do: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Comment: not sure how you click on something when it is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
coll[0].onclick = () => {
  if (coll[0].style.display === 'block') {
    coll[0].style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    coll[0].style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```css
.collection {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
coll[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (coll[0].style.display = "block") {
    coll[0].style.display = "none";
}

});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your event listener, you can use this ternary operator:

```
coll[0].style.display === 'block'? coll[0].style.display = "hidden" : coll[0].style.display = "block"
```

You can learn more about [ternary operators here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: This isn't really the correct answer, you are not answering his main concern. He is asking how to make the click listener, and then checking whether the coll element is hidden oder visible.